# Error when using component npm?

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to use an npm library in my react-native app. but I have this error

I'm using [cielo library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cielo)

and I'm importing to my project

```
import cielo from 'cielo';
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Please add complete error you are having and please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Look at github source code of this package [here](https://github.com/banzeh/cielo).
It seems you have to pass some parameter when importing this package. You can take a look at usage example of this package [here](https://github.com/banzeh/cielo/blob/master/cielo.test.js). Your import code seems to be wrong...